# Eureka 2.0 is discontinued. What service discovery platform is Netflix using now?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix, service-discovery, netflix

According to the Eureka wiki (https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki), the Eureka 2.0 has been discontinued.

> The open source work on eureka 2.0 has been discontinued. The code base and artifacts that were released as part of the existing repository of work on the 2.x branch is considered use at your own risk.

**Questions**

1. What is new in Eureka 2.0 compared to Eureka 1.0 (which Spring Cloud 2.0 is still using)?
2. Does Netflix still use any service discovery platform internally? If yes, what is it?

**Edit**

1. Found some answers for the first question. Read these:

   - Eureka 2.0 Motivation, https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-2.0-Motivations
   - Eureka 2.0 Architecture Overview, https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-2.0-Architecture-Overview
   - Eureka 2.0 Client Configuration And Use, https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-2.0-Client-Configuration-And-Use
   - Eureka 2.0 Server Configuration And Use, https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Eureka-2.0-Server-Configuration-And-Use

Comment: You now using Spring Cloud Alibaba Nacos Server instead Eureka Server, it is more powerful than the Eureka.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eureka 2 was an experiment that ended not being used. Netflix still uses eureka 1.

Comment: Is this different from Spring Cloud? Isn't that using Eureka 2? Should we be using that starter or one of the 1.x ones? It seems like you are currently working on the 2.x starter...

Comment: Spring Cloud imports the 1.9.x version of eureka

Answer (score 0):

According to eureka wiki --> eureka 2 is [discontinued](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki), but the latest version of spring cloud --> compatible with spring boot 3 is using eureka 2.

**spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client** --> [Dependencies](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud/spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client/4.0.0#:%7E:text=Compile%20Dependencies)

Comment: The NEW eureka 2 is eureka 1 with support for jakarta.* rather than java.*, Not the rearchitected 2.